# Creating an algorithm for 2d cutting stock problem

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I am going to try and make django/react web app of a solver to 2 dimensional [cutting stock problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem)

I am kinda lost with all the math in the papers online.

I did make a greedy algorithm successfully but i want a more efficient solution. Is there any resources/methods that may help me start in the algorithm?

Comment: This video shows a tracing of an algorithm... jump to the 5-minute mark: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3VMTQkCceI